# How to access a child component class from the parent component class in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular

In Angular 2 how do you access a child component class from the parent component class? e.g.

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({selector: 'child'})
@View({template: `...`})
class Child {
    doSomething() {
        console.log('something');
    }
}

@Component({selector: 'parent'})
@View({
    directives: [Child],
    template: `<child></child>`
})
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        //TODO: call child.doSomething() when the child component is ready
    }
}
```

In this example how would I call the `Child` component's `doSomething()` method from either the `Parent` component's constructor or some callback function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite simple but you have to keep a few points in mind which I'll detail below, first the code.

To reference your children, in this case you want your children within your View, so you must use `@ViewChildren` and you must wait the view to be initialized so you do

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    template: `<child></child>`,
    directives : [Child]
})
export class Parent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(Child) children: QueryList<Child>;

  afterViewInit() {
    for(let child of this.children) {
      child.doSomething();
    }
  }

}
```

**Note**

The loop inside `afterViewInit()` will work if you are transpiling to ES6 since angular2 internally uses [`Symbol.iterator`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/query_list.ts#L59). If you are transpiling to ES5 you'll have to workaround it since typescript [does not support it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2207#issuecomment-77609809) (see plnkr for workaround).

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8cymoD).

I hope it helps :)

Comment: In my case I only have one child component so I'm just using `this.children.first`. Thanks!

Comment: @rob If you need only one child component then use [`@ViewChild`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/di.ts#L353) instead of `@ViewChildren`

Comment: Oh even better. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to access one specific child using an ID or something? Just like getElementById in JS.

Comment: Also in the cheat sheet here https://angular.io/cheatsheet it says "not for directives". Is there ant other way to do this?

Comment: @DorukEker, see [QueryMetadata](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/QueryMetadata-class.html).  `ViewChild` uses the same query parameters, except for `descendants`.  So you can declare a local template variable on a component or an element using `#` (e.g., `#myLtv`) and then use `@ViewChild('myLtv')` to get a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ViewChild` in you parent component to accesss any methods of child components.

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'parent',
      directives: [Child]
    })

    export class Parent {
        @ViewChild(Child) childComponent: Child;

        ngAfterViewInit() {
        // The child is available here
        childComponent.doSomething();
      }
    }
```

Note: This code snippet is for angular2 rc4 version.